# How to get dates outside of the date range between two dates?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, date-range

I'll get to the point. So I have two dates, it could be any dates. for example

1. 2023-03-01 and 2023-03-03
2. 2023-03-12 and 2023-03-20
3. 2023-04-10 and 2023-05-15

All these dates have a date range. like

1. 2023-03-01, 2023-03-02, and 2023-03-03

and so on...

So is it possible to get the dates that are NOT in those date range ? If it's possible how ?

Because I want to get the dates that are NOT in those date range to disable in my AspxDateEdit. For now I write my code like this :

```
    Private Function getDateRange() As IEnumerable(Of Date)
        Dim dates = New List(Of Date)()
        Dim dateRange As Date = clsCommon.ToDate(lblHiddenDateFrom.Text)

        While dateRange <= clsCommon.ToDate(lblHiddenDateTo.Text)
            dates.Add(dateRange.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            dateRange = dateRange.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        End While
        Return dates
        'lblHiddenDateFrom.Text and lblHiddenDateTo.Text are the two dates. 
    End Function

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      datepickerSearchApprovalFrom.DisabledDates.AddRange(getDateRange()) 'this is not what I wanted because it disable the date range that are not suppose to disable. 
    End Sub
```

If there is another way for me to disable those dates that NOT in the date range between two dates also do tell me. I've been stuck for 2 weeks by now. Thanks

Comment: Your description is poor but I think I understand what you're getting at. In your example, you have three date ranges. If you create an overall range from the earliest date in those three ranges to the latest date, are you saying that you want dates that are in that overall range but not in any of the three original ranges? If not, what are you saying?

Comment: @jmcilhinney what I'm saying is, I want to disable the dates in my AspxDateEdit that are NOT in the date ranges. It could be the overall ranges of the three dates or could be not. So let say I have a date range from 2023-03-10 to 2023-03-20, right. I want the dates in the range can be select by user while the other dates that are NOT in the date range to disable. In short, how to disable the dates that are NOT in the date range ? Because, with my way, it disable the dates in the date range. That's not what I wanted.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to explain it anymore to make people understand but the point is I want to disable the dates that NOT in the date range between two dates.

Comment: I don't know exactly how that particular control works but I can make some educated guesses. In order to provide an answer though, I'll still need more information. It appears that you can specify a range of dates to disable or, presumably, a single date. In order to specify all dates to be disabled, you're going to need to know what the minimum date and maximum date are that it will display. You can then specify a range from the control's minimum date to your minimum date and a range from your maximum date to the control's maximum date. Do you know those values or how to get them?

Comment: Once you've disabled those leading and trailing ranges, you can look at the ones between your ranges. They could be done as individual dates or ranges. Is the number of ranges you will have always three or is it arbitrary? Can those ranges overlap? If not, can they be adjacent, i.e. no gap between them?

Comment: the ranges can be anything like 2023-03-01 to 2023-03-03 then another range like 2023-03-20 to 2023-03-25. or even a single date like you said. if you ask me do I know those values and how to get them is yes and no. I know how if there are min and max dates. the min and max dates I get it from my database. You can see it in my code I showed at `getDateRange` function. So, the `lblHiddenDateFrom` and `lblHiddenDateTo` are the min and max dates. Those date range from the `lblHiddenDateFrom` and `lblHiddenDateTo`  is the range that I wish to enable while the other dates/range is disable.

Comment: -continuation ... My problem is, I want to enable the dates range that I wrote like in my code while disable the others.